# sunburst plot rounding counts in R when it shouldn't

Tags: r, sunburst-diagram

The sunburstR package rounds counts without the user asking too. How can I change this behavior? Below the numbers will display as 810, 120, 140 respectively. This doesn't happen when numbers are < 100. From the documentation there doesn't seem to be a way to address this.

```
library(sunburstR)
df <- data.frame(path = c("A","B","C"),
                 pop = c(808,124,136))
sunburst(df, count = TRUE, width = "100%",
         height = 400)
```